# how to pass data between these two view controllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, visual-c++, storyboard, viewcontroller

in this case i have tabbar controller and navigation controller between the 
two VC,which means firstly i want to pass data between the first VC and the tabbar controller, and secondly i want to pass the same data from the tab bar controller to navigation controller , and finnally to the last VC,i searched for example in the net but i didn't find anything useful.

[image: pass data]

please can u help me pass data between these two viewcontrollers ,any example will be great, thaank's.

Answer (score 2):

Set an identifier to the segue in your storyboard (click on the segue and then on the right menu go to attributes inspector) and then you probably need to click on the cell to make the segue in `didSelectRowAt`, do this in there:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YOUR IDENTIFIER", sender: DATA TO PASS or nil)
```

And then create the segue function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!){
    if (segue.identifier == "YOUR IDENTIFIER") // good to have if you have multiple segues
    {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.str = "DATA" // now you can access public variables and functions from the second viewController
    }
}
```

Comment: `sender:
The object that initiated the segue. You might use this parameter to perform different actions based on which control (or other object) initiated the segue.` This shouldn't be used to pass data

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @Rashwan L answer, and pass the infobetween all controllers until the last, or simply create a variable in the AppDelegate and use it when the desired controller arrives.

```
var App: AppDelegate {
    return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
}
```

`App.myVar = "My DATA"`

and when use you can get with `App.myVar`

Comment: creating a globally accessible variable via the app delegate is a very bad pattern to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure this out for a while. Currently, I create a property to hold the data that I want to pass, right before I call `performSelector:`, then use that property to pass the data into the appropriate view controller in `prepareForSegue:`. After its used, I nil out the data. Looks like this

```
@property (...) NSString *selectedString;

- (void)methodThatPicksTheData {
  self.selectedString = @"someString";
  [self performSegue:kSegueIdentifier];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(SegueClassWhoseNameICannotRememberRightNow)segue {

  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kSegueIdentifier]) {
     CustomViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
     vc.string = self.selectedString;
     self.selectedString = nil;
  }

}
```

its not perfect, but it provides a way to clearly designate what data needs to get passed.