# Passing the Boolean Flag between the views in swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I have a single view controller containing the some text labels and multiple other properties. I want to use that view controller for both editing the view and viewing the contents of view. Now what I want to do is pass the Flag so that it indicates whether the request is for editing the fields or viewing the fields.

I have done this but did not work. Lets say my view controller containing the view is third View Controller and I am accessing this view controller from first and second view controller.

```
//In third View COntroller
var isEdit: Bool! = false
func viewDidLoad(){
    self.loadData()
}
 override func loadData{
    if isEdit == false{
       //print this is edit mode
    }
    else if isEdit == true{
      //This is view mode
    }
  else{
  //print error navigtion
     }
}
```

and I am accessing to this view controller from first view controller on button click action as

```
let mapViewFirst = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController
mapViewFirst.isEdit == true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewFirst!, animated: true)
```

and from secondViewController as

```
let mapViewSecond = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController
mapViewSecond.isEdit == false
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewSecond!, animated: true)
```

it always runs on `isEdit == false`
i.e the view controller is always on Edit mode it never moves to else condition. Can anyone find the better solution to my issue.

Comment: You have a variable called `isEdit` but the thing you set is called `iseditMode`...how is that supposed to work?  Also, why is `isEdit` an unwrapped optional instead of a plain `Bool`?  Even stranger, the view controllers you instantiate aren't the same view controllers that you push.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be    override func viewDidLoad()? is that even being called?

Comment: sorry for the mistakes,now i have added the clarity to my questions. every thing now is working except it  always execute on isEdit == false. So what am i wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the difference between isEdit and iseditMode is a typo in your question and not in your actual code, and also that the difference between mapViewFirst and mapViewControllerObj and mapViewSecond and mapViewControllerObj are also just typos in your question and not your actual code.

Then it is not working because viewDidLoad() is called when the view controller is loaded into memory, which is occurring when instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is called.

To get the functionality you want move loadData() from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear which will get called when the view controller is pushed to the stack. (and make sure you override viewWillAppear as you are supposed to, not like you have omitted from viewDidLoad())

Comment: ok i have edited my questions. It was isEdit not is editmode. still i am not getting desired output it always runs on isEdit == fasle. can you please help me out

Comment: Do you have segues between your scenes in the storyboard? If so you should be using the segues to move between view controllers and not trying to create and push them onto the stack yourself. If you are using segues there are many many past questions how to pass data between view controllers i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921558/how-to-pass-data-between-these-two-view-controllers-in-swift